# Sitecore 9 Forms Custom Submit Model called twice

Tags: sitecore-forms

I've implemented a Sitecore 9 Forms Custom Submit Model referring to this article:

https://www.codinglittlethings.com/2019/10/sitecore-9-forms-google-recaptcha-field.html

The only difference is, I am using Google ReCaptcha V3 instead of V2 (as in above article)

I have placed my Custom Model above the SaveData method in the Form Action:

[image]

**Now the issue is - when I hit the submit button, it successfully validates the Captcha and submits the form and returns true. When I press F5 (while debugging in Visual Studio), it again hits the break-point I have placed same Custom Submit Model and this time the Captcha validation fails (with duplicate error)**

Please point out, what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Hello @SitecoreSXADeveloper, I am also facing the same issue, did you find any solution?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you press F5, you resubmit the request with the same data. It's logical that the captcha payload is not valid anymore on the second request.

You could add a redirect submit action to have the form redirect on submit, so that F5 won't resubmit the request.

Comment: Hello Bart, I am sorry for not being clear. By F5 I meant in Visual Studio while debugging the code. And even without debugging I am unable to submit, since the method is called twice. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

In the forms setting, uncheck the "Ajax Enable" checkbox will solve the problem. But the only side affect is it will load the page and then will show the success message.

Thanks