# What would cause a Sitecore Form to duplicate submit?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have created a custom submit based on the below module:

https://www.nishtechinc.com/Blog/2018/April/Send-E-mail-Action-to-Sitecore-9-Forms

It went all hunky dory on my dev machine but when moved to our staging environment it started submitting twice and thus sending two emails. I added some logging to my custom code and it is definitely a submit of the same form as the SessionId, TemplateId etc. are all identical.

During my frantic googling I came across the below question on stack exchange which looks like the same problem but there wasn't an answer given.

[Sitecore 9 Forms Custom Submit Model called twice](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24513/sitecore-9-forms-custom-submit-model-called-twice)

The bit I am missing is what happens between the form being submitted and it hitting the execute method on my submit action. Any pointers on where I can troubleshoot around that would be great.

I am stumped with the above so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Cheers

Shaun

P.s This is my first time asking a question on StackExchange so please let me know if my question could have been clearer and/or more helpful.

Comment: is it enable Ajax Post check box?  If is enabled can you disabled it and check again ?

Comment: @VladIobagiu Thanks for reply. Just tried the above and when submitting I get an error.

Comment: @VladIobagiu I will post the error above as it is too long for comments. Thanks for the advice I'll look at why my forms are erroring without Ajax

Comment: @VladIobagiu just realised that adding the error above may muddy the water somewhat so here's the error on this question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23759/sitecore-forms-save-submit-action-null-formdatamodel

Comment: when you submit do you see 2 formsbuilder in the network tab in Chrome/ Developer Tools , something like : formbuilder?fxb.FormItemId=5fd6197f-ffdb-4426-9298-07eaf4865b02&fxb.HtmlPrefix=fxb.24481816-6c0e-49fb-bf2b-2275e185ffb1

Comment: @VladIobagiu the above is what I see when Ajax is enabled but now the form is submitting to {pageName}?sc_site=website

Comment: @VladIobagiu just to be clear I checked and there are two submits in the network tab when Ajax is enabled. Sorry if I was unclear above.

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Is there any solution on this? FYI I checked on network tab on chrome debugger I can see 2 formsbuilder

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with Sitecore forms submit when Ajax was enabled (not submit duplication though).
The solution in was to edit: \Views\FormBuilder\Form.cshtml and add @**Html.RenderFormStyles()** above form definition and **@Html.RenderFormScripts()** below form definition like so:

```
@Html.RenderFormStyles()

@{
    using (Html.BeginRenderRouteForm(Model, IsPost))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Hidden(AttributeNames.FormItemId, Model.ItemId)
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.RenderFields(Model)
        <input type="hidden" data-sc-fxb-condition value='@Html.RenderConditions(Model)' />
    }
}

@Html.RenderFormScripts()
```

Comment: This fix also fixed my problem where an ajax call on the form submission would result in an unstyled form being returned in the response. The url would be weird having "/formbuilder" being included in the address.
I think this is actually a call to a Sitecore api. When I modified the Form.cshtml file as described, the form would validate and submit using ajax correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, how many times the forms scripts are getting loaded. We were having same scenario for ajax enabled checkbox and after checking the html by inspecting, the script reference was twice.